# jquery row highlighting with exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue where highlighting a row in onclick in jquery won't allow me to access a link in said row.

My solution is to highlight all `<td>` except the one with the link. Here's kind of what I'm thinking:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#List tr td").not(td[id*=NOTES]).click(function()) {
            $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("highlighted");
            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
        };
    });
```

Here's what I was using originally:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#RegistrantList tr td").click(function()) {
        $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("highlighted");
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    };
});
```

Am I on the right track? Or is there a much simpler way to do this?

Relevant [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ourweakness/yjkWX/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: You are currently removing the class from `tr` elements but adding to `td`.. so it will not work.. But you should really try to solve the actual problem which needs a bit more describing..

Comment: I agree, I don't understand why this code won't allow you to "access a link in said row"

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yeh, plus the lack of quotes for the string `td[id*=NOTES]` - I guess we need a fiddle before we can address the issue.

Comment: `$("#List tr td").not('td[id*=NOTES]')`  <----you need to add quotes around the selector

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah, but quotes let you save namespace or whatever

Comment: @DavidThomas i'm sure quotes are needed there around the selector - they just aren't required for the attributes selector

Comment: @DavidThomas He has `.not(td[id*=NOTES])`.. it needs to at least be `.not('td[id*=NOTES]')`. As he has it, `td[id*=NOTES]` isn't a string literal.

Comment: I'm srs confused... hah - I think @DavidThomas is missing the fact that it's not a string in the first place. I'm not saying the attribute selection inside can't be parsed without quotes...

Comment: Updated with relevant [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ourweakness/yjkWX/)